# Trying to implement JSON in a bottom navigation view Layout with fragments

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I am trying to create a project which has a bottom navigation view in the main activity and 4 fragment. I wish to parse JSON and update the data in one of the fragment which should display the information. My code parses data from the main activity but i am getting an error.I keep getting an

Main Activity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView infectedCaseCount;
TextView deceasedCaseCount;
TextView recoveredCaseCount;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
Button parseBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new CasesFragment()).commit();

    infectedCaseCount = findViewById(R.id.infectedCaseCount);
    deceasedCaseCount = findViewById(R.id.deceasedCaseCount);
    recoveredCaseCount = findViewById(R.id.recoveredCaseCount);
    parseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.parseBtn);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    parseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            jsonParse();
        }
    });





}

public void jsonParse() {
        String url="https://api.covid19api.com/summary";
         JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                 try {
                     JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Global");

                     for(int i=0;i< jsonArray.length();i++)
                     {
                         JSONObject global = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         String TotalConfirmed = global.getString("TotalConfirmed");
                         String TotalDeaths = global.getString("TotalDeaths");
                         String TotalRecovered = global.getString("TotalRecovered");

                         infectedCaseCount.setText(TotalConfirmed);
                         deceasedCaseCount.setText(TotalDeaths);
                         recoveredCaseCount.setText(TotalRecovered);

                     }
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 error.printStackTrace();
             }
         });
         requestQueue.add(request);
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
               Fragment selectedFragment = null;

               switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
                   case R.id.updates:
                       selectedFragment = new CasesFragment();
                       break;
                   case R.id.symptoms:
                       selectedFragment = new SymptomsFragment();
                       break;
                   case R.id.safety:
                       selectedFragment = new SafetyFragment();
                       break;
                   case R.id.contact:
                       selectedFragment = new FragmentContact();
                       break;
               }
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
               return true;
            }
        };


}
```

Fragment Page XML

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"

    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/parseBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearAboveButton"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Get Info!"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/globalSituation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
        android:text="Global Situation"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDescription"
        android:textSize="30sp" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/linearAboveButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/totCase"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/deceasedData"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#E7F8FA"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
                    android:text="Recovered"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recoveredCaseCount"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                    android:text="4345677"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/actCases"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />


            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/activeData"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#E7F8FA"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"

            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
                    android:text="Deceased"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/deceasedCaseCount"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                    android:text="4345677"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/decCases"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/totCase"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/globalSituation"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#E7F8FA"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/regular"
                android:text="Infected"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/infectedCaseCount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                android:text="4345677"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/totCases"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment.java

```
public class CasesFragment extends Fragment {


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cases,container,false);


}
}
```

ERROR

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.coronavirustracker, PID: 28827
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.coronavirustracker/com.example.coronavirustracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.coronavirustracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

CasesFragment

```
public class CasesFragment extends Fragment {

TextView infectedCaseCount;
TextView deceasedCaseCount;
TextView recoveredCaseCount;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
Button parseBtn;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    parseBtn = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.parseBtn);
    infectedCaseCount = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.infectedCaseCount);
    deceasedCaseCount = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.deceasedCaseCount);
    recoveredCaseCount = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recoveredCaseCount);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    parseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            jsonParse();
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cases,container,false);


}
public void jsonParse() {
    String url="https://api.covid19api.com/summary";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Global");

                for(int i=0;i< jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject global = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String TotalConfirmed = global.getString("TotalConfirmed");
                    String TotalDeaths = global.getString("TotalDeaths");
                    String TotalRecovered = global.getString("TotalRecovered");

                    infectedCaseCount.setText(TotalConfirmed);
                    deceasedCaseCount.setText(TotalDeaths);
                    recoveredCaseCount.setText(TotalRecovered);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
}
```

New Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.coronavirustracker, PID: 29961
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.coronavirustracker.CasesFragment.onCreateView(CasesFragment.java:45)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: I corrected it, it still gives the same error.

Comment: On the button. I changed the scrollview id, and gave the button the id of parseBtn

Comment: it reverts me back to  parseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: Did you try initializing the views in the casesfragment class?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the main class to initialize the Views that are present in your Fragment. You should initialize then in your Fragment class and not the main class.

Inside casefragment

`button =getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_paresbt);`

Infact you should move this entire code to the fragment

```
infectedCaseCount = findViewById(R.id.infectedCaseCount);
deceasedCaseCount = findViewById(R.id.deceasedCaseCount);
recoveredCaseCount = findViewById(R.id.recoveredCaseCount);
parseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.parseBtn);


parseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        jsonParse();
    }
});
}
```